# "Could not find acceptable representation" when throwing custom exception

Tags: java, spring-boot

Using spring boot version 1.3.3.RELEASE...

I have a resource method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@NotNull @PathVariable("id") String imageId) {
    // get image from database and return byte[]
    if(image == null) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("...");
    }
}
```

Where `ResourceNotFoundException` is a simple class like this:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ResourceNotFoundException() {
    }

    public ResourceNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public ResourceNotFoundException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

This methodology works well for all other resources, but I think it gets into a muddle either with the required `byte[]` response body or the fact that it is producing `APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE`. Whenever the code gets to the exception, I have this in my logs (and the client actually receives a 500 rather than a 404):

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:251) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
 ...
```

Is there any way I can use custom exceptions in this case? I suppose I can use the `ResponseEntity`builders, but would be nice to be consistent.

Thanks in advance.